# Basic communication between Cotek and Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I am trying to get a reading from my Cotek through my Arduino and have it display on an LCD screen. When I run the code, though, nothing shows up. I am EXTREMELY new to using pretty much all this equipment so honestly, I have little to no idea what I'm doing. I am not sure if it is a wiring issue, an issue with the code or both. Any and all help is appreciated.

This is how the cotek is wired to the Arduino. The middle red wire (in the middle of the two resistors) is connected to AUX from the cotek. The two outer red wires are connected to the SDA and SCL of the cotek and their corresponding blue wires are connected to the SDA and SCL of the Arduino (the two resistors are 2KOhm pull-up resistors). The blue wire on the bottom is connected to the GRND of the cotek which is also connected to GRND of the Arduino. 
[image: connection from cotek to arduino]

This is my code using the I2C protocol:

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Wire.h>

int analogPin = 5;
char address= 0;
int numBytes = 2;
char val = 0;
int debug = 5;
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Wire.requestFrom(address, numBytes);
  while(Wire.available())
  {
    val = Wire.read();
    Serial.print(val);
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print(val);
  }
  //perform function to change val from hexadecimal to decimal number here
  delay(500);
```

I am pretty sure the LCD is wired correctly to the Arduino as I was able to communicate to it previously without using the Cotek. In any case, it doesn't matter as 'val' doesn't even appear on the serial monitor.

Again, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's a Cotek?

Comment: Surely the Cotek does not use address 0? `char address= 0;` See [my I2C page](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10896&reply=6#reply6) for a small scanner that will tell you the address of any I2C devices. This would also confirm that your wiring is OK.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried running the code for the scanner and in my Serial monitor, all I got are random symbols that change each time I run it.